# How to open my workplace folder directly in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to ask how I can open my workplace folder(where eclipse save the data) directly in Eclipse.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "Eclipse Plugin". You can google something like "explorer plugin in eclipse", it give you a lot of choices (like Eclipse Explorer, StartExplore,...etc). Go to their's home page and install as it's said.

You can also go directly to [eclipse market page](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-explorer) and search.